# Word for "it is so because we say so, period."

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

What's a word for the reasoning / leadership mindset of "it is so because we say so"? Or a regime / rule based on such a mindset, with the issuing of unexplained and seemingly arbitrary decrees, with the implication being the leaders are above (or not bound by) the need to explain / justify their decisions. Essentially no reasons / explanations are or need to be provided with their rulings.

Comment: Please/rewrite/this/question/without/slashes/which/confuse/us.

Comment: **Fiat**.  Latin "let it be".  Vernacular "because I said so."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

> **appeal to authority**
> The informal fallacy of claiming that we ought to accept the truth of a proposition because of some personal feature of the individual who affirms it.
> [Philosophical Dictionary](http://www.philosophypages.com/dy/a9.htm#auth)

Answer (score 1):

One word for this is **conclusive**. One definition [in Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conclusive)

> putting an end to debate or question especially by reason of irrefutability

Conclusive, decisive, or especially inarguable are normally used when there are good reasons for the decision.  When there are none, and the only reason for the decision is that an authority said so, it is **arbitrary**. A more neutral synonym is **final** (as in, "this decision is final.”)

A decision that cannot be appealed is **unreviewable** or **unappealable**.  Someone who cannot be overruled is **unaccountable** or **autocratic**.

Some phrases for this include **pulling rank**, or that a decision is **not open for discussion**.